# The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format - In .plist

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Sample & Test</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>Icon.png</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>Icon.png</string>
        <string>Icon-72.png</string>
        <string>Icon-114.png</string>
        <string>Icon-144.png</string>
        <string>Icon-76.png</string>
        <string>Icon-120.png</string>
        <string>Icon-152.png</string>
        <string>Icon-180.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UILaunchImages</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 480}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>9.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 480}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-ios8</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 480}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-568h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>9.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-568h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-568h-ios8</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-667h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{375, 667}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>9.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-667h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{375, 667}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-667h-ios8</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{375, 667}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-736h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{414, 736}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-736h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{414, 736}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-iPad</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{768, 1024}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-iPad</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Landscape</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{768, 1024}</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIStatusBarTintParameters</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UINavigationBar</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Style</key>
            <string>UIBarStyleDefault</string>
            <key>TintColor</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Blue</key>
                <real>1</real>
                <key>Green</key>
                <real>0.0</real>
                <key>Red</key>
                <real>0.0</real>
            </dict>
            <key>Translucent</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is my plist file in objective c, i'm trying to open on this file in xcode8.2 getting the 
**Error: "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format"**.

This is  the old project, i don't know which xcode version they are used for develop, but now i'm using xcode 8.2.

Please help me to solve this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Line 8 contains an & (ampersand) character which should be escaped by using the `&amp;` XML entity, like this:

```
<string>Sample &amp; Test</string>
```

Please refer to this solution when checking plist files:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15489496/3151675

You should run `plutil <path to file>` in Terminal to get an output which tells you the incorrect line.